# Using Boolean for left/right in twostack

Tags: java, stack, boolean

I have a task at school. This involves making a twostack array using boolean value true/false to get acess to right/left in the stacks.

Im kind of green using stacks at all! And dont know how to implement this boolean s*t

Any tips? Unfinished code extract below: 
...

```
/**
 * Stacks of top-element of given stack and return it.
 * @param right true if right stable, false if left stable
 * @throws TwostackEmptyException if stable is empty
 */
@Override
public Object pop(Boolean right) throws TwostackEmptyException {
    return null;
}

/**
 *  Return top element of given stack, but doesnt remove it.
 *  @param right true if right, false if left
 *  @throws TwostackEmptyException if stacks empty.
 */
@Override
public Object peek(Boolean right) throws TwostackEmptyException {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You may want two stacks in your `Twostack` class. Based on `Boolean right` you perform the transaction needed (like `pop` or `peek`) on one of them.

Comment: They are supposed to be full when they "meet in the middle" so in the constructors a "twostack" is made, either by: a fixed size of 100, and the other constructor: a chosen size. So should I make the size of 100 to be 50/50 on the twostack or is it a way to implement it in one "double stack" from two sides like: [1,2,3........n-3,n-2,n-1]...? Confused!

Comment: If you had a fixed size for each, there would be no benefit over having two separate stacks. You should have a single storage area; that way you can put 80 objects in one side, 10 in the other side, and it's still not full.  That is essentially required by "full when they meet in the middle" - if you had fixed 50 for each side, then one could be full and yet the stacks had not met (because the other one is not full).

Comment: @another-dave thats exactly what I want! But I am not sure on how two make it ...

Comment: Is there a requirement on the underlying storage used? Any collection, only one collection, Array, ...

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the basic form of making a two-stack array; taking a regular array and 'splitting' it in half.

If your array is max size N, then the "left" side of the array stretches from "array[0]" to "array[n/2]" (the half way mark.)

The "right" side will be from "array[n/2]" to "array[n-1]" (the end).

So for example, if we want to put a toy car into the left side of our "ToyCollection" array, that is size 10? Then we can put it into "ToyCollection[0-4]", the first half. We only put action figures into slots "ToyCollection[5-9]".

Note we aren't literally *splitting* the array in half, but we're telling ourselves that we won't put certain items in certain slots.

So how to work booleans into this? Well for my above example, let's say that we have a boolean that says "WantToyCars". If this bool is True, then we only want access to the *left* side of the array.

So let's return a split of that. There are several ways to split arrays, but I'm just going to use the built-in "copyOfRange" function that all arrays have. Some pseudocode to illustrate the idea;

```
public Toy[] getCars(Toy[] ToyCollection, boolean WantToyCars) {
     if (WantToyCars) {
        Toy[] ToyCars = Arrays.copyOfRange(ToyCollection, 1, (ToyCollection.length / 2));
        return ToyCars;
     }
}
```

If that fits the structure of your assignment, then I think that'll do the trick.

Comment: I want it to be like @another Dave said in comment, so the size isnt "fixed on both sides. If one side has 10 elements, the other can have 90 and so on. But how can I make it boolean ? Will I have to do like you: to have another variable declared boolean ( here WantToyCars?) Here is some code from the first constructor:     public TwoStackArray()
    {
        arr = new int[100];
        size = 100;
        right = -1;
        left = size;

Comment: If you want an array that does not have a fixed size, can you use an ArrayList? You can change its size then at any time, unlike a normal array. Do you know much about them?

I'm not sure how else booleans could interact with this; maybe the assignment question's precise wording contains a clue?

Comment: Also @Muriel you can probably make the two stack sides meet by adding a "partition" variable, a number that is greater than 0 but less than n (where n = array's max size). The size of stack 1 ends at n, which is where stack 2 begins. You can refer to this in the array as something like "Array[n]", or "myArrayList.get(n)".

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try to define the boolean in the method; something like " if (right) { add the stuff to the right stack} else { add to other stack} something like that...

Comment: And I think the two sides challenge gets solved by defining right as : right = size; and left = -1...I can post the finish code here afterwards if I manage :P

Comment: Fingers crossed. Let us know how you get on! @Muriel

Comment: I'm skimming, but I haven't seen it explicitly said here.  If you're building this in (say) an array Object[N], then one stack is growing from 0 upwards, and the other is growing from N-1 (the last allocated element) downwards.  I don't know what level the class is at, i.e., how proficient people are expected to be, but in general I'd expect to see no shuffling of array content.

Comment: @NoStupidQuestions , posted my finished boolean method....plus a new problem which arised :P